# MongoDB: Set collection level pessimistic lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, concurrency, mongoid

I am running a ton of background jobs and keep running into a race condition on one particular job.

Rails 4, Mongoid, Sidekiq, Redis

Profile has_many ProfilePictures

When this code is called by multiple threads

```
  def set_as_active_picture
    ProfilePicture.where({
      profile_id: self.profile.id,
      selected: true}
    ).update_all('$set' => {selected: false})

    self.set selected: true

    self.profile.set(picture_url: self.image.url)
  end
```

I hit a race condition where multiple ProfilePicture documents have selected set to true.

What I would like to do is set a pessimistic lock on a set of ProfilePicture documents which satisfy profile_id == self.profile_id or at least on the ProfilePicture collection.

I can't find anything about native locking for Mongoid or Mongo, so I looked to some gems.

I added afeld/mongoid-locker but this only works on single model instances. I tried adding both trakio/mongo-lock and servio/mongo-locking, but could not figure out how to use mongo-lock (what does 'my_key' reference?) and mongo-locking is giving me a source error for Active_Support 3.0.4

How can I place a pessimistic lock on the set of ProfilePicture documents who belong to a specific Profile document?

Comment: you running in a classic mongodb problem - if its possible get rid of it asap - good reads to this: http://developer.olery.com/blog/goodbye-mongodb-hello-postgresql/ - https://hn.algolia.com/?query=mongo&sort=byPopularity&prefix&page=0&dateRange=all&type=story

Comment: Haha, you are saying this is a classic mongodb problem? Great, just one more reason I hate mongo. I would love to switch to something like postgres but unfortunately its not my decision.

Answer (score 0):

For those who care, I was able to work around this problem by removing the selected attribute from the profile_picture model and instead adding a selected_pic_id attribute to the profile model. This allowed me to atomically update the profile model instead of trying to update the collection of profile_picture documents.